# How to handle Animal AI biting and holding onto the character

Tags: unity, c#, animation, ai

Example state of decay, zombie biting the player

Comment: This question would be clearer if you included in the body of the question 1) actual image/gif/video examples of the interaction you have in mind, 2) a description of how you've tried reproducing this interaction in Unity so far, and 3) a description of the problems with that approach, how it's behaving differently from what you need. This focuses answers on solving the specific issues you need help with.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you'd like more useful answers.